# Exchange Online MailFlow Rule - Identify recipient group by display name

Tags: outlook, office365, exchange-server

Using O365 Exchange Online, I have a scenario where I've got a bunch of distribution lists whose display name is in the format "CDL-blahblah" but their email address is not necessarily predictable. I want to prepend a disclaimer on messages such as these using an Exchange Mail Flow Rule. I have attempted variations of the following, but this does not seem to identify messages to these lists correctly:

[image: properties match pattern]
[image: include words]

Answer (score 0):

There are other sites where you can learn and test regular expressions.
• https://regex101.com/
• https://regexr.com/
• http://regexstorm.net/tester
• https://regexlib.com/RETester.aspx

I don't think you need to add 'DisplayName:' in the condition.
everything that starts with CDL, would be like 'CDL.+' or 'CDL.*'.